# Send large file over BLE with ESP32 Wrover B

Tags: esp32, ble, littlefs

I have been able to get a large file to be sent in packages over BLE to a characteristic on my ESP32-Wrover-B module (yay!). However, these files can be large (+300kb) so I need to repackage them after all the file data has been sent (in chunks), to then be stored/written in LittleFS.

I have PSRAM with my module that will allow me to store in a larger space directly, however, from the tutorials I have read, you cannot create a global char* variable for PSRAM.

What would be my best approach here? My basic logic here is to repackage all the chunks that are received via BLE into a char* (or string). Once all data received,  save it as a file in LittleFS.

Comment: Use a buffer array to receive the chunk then write to the file once the chunk is received completely.
This is what I utilized for transferring the OTA update file (~1.2MB) over BLE [ESP32_BLE_OTA_Arduino](https://github.com/fbiego/ESP32_BLE_OTA_Arduino)